# Show and hide tables in Word 2010 when a checkbox is selected/deselected

Tags: forms, checkbox, ms-word

Anyone knows how to show and hide a table in Microsoft Word 2010 when a checkbox is selected or deselected?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think this is built in to Word; you're probably going to need to do a little scripting with VBA to make it happen. 
Here's a resource with a couple of options to get you started: http://gregmaxey.mvps.org/word_tip_pages/toggle_data_display.html

You might also consider creating your table as an embedded Excel document and using Excel's hide/show functionality.